# JavaScript - How to get $value of $key of item?

Tags: javascript

I have item that contain array of values and keys such as this picture

[image]

I solved the problem with poor solution

```
item.forEach(element=>{
    if(element.$key=='fname'){this.user.fname=element.$value;}
    if(element.$key=='lname'){this.user.lname=element.$value;}
});
```

Is there any faster solution ?

for example:

```
this.user.fname= //something to get the value of fname
```

Comment: You could set `this.user[element.$key] = element.$value` I guess, although whether or not that meets your *actual* needs is tough to guess.

Comment: It would be better if you would not provide the image of how something looks in the console, but instead would include the object(s) as plain JavaScript literals (not an image).

Comment: @DaveNewton your solution works fine :) .. thank u so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create keys dynamically:

```
item.forEach(element=> this.user[$element.key] = $element.value);
```

or using ES6 destructuring:

```
item.forEach(({$key, $value}) => this.user[$key] = $value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ES6 [computed property name syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) together with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const item = [
    { $value: "John", $key: "fname" },
    { $value: "McEnroe", $key: "lname" }    
];

const user = Object.assign(...item.map(o => ({[o.$key]: o.$value})));

console.log(user);
```